# get a single row from db, remove one element from row and update that row back to db

Tags: mysql, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

I want to get a single row from db, remove one element from row and update that row back to db.

I wrote this code

```
$query = $this->db->get_where(TABLENAME, array('pin_code' => $pincode), 1);

$result = $query->result_array();

$array = $result[0]; 

if (($key = array_search($ccode, $array)) !== false) {
            unset($array[$key]);
} //$code is the value which i want to remove

$this->db->where('pin_code', $pincode);
$this->db->update(TABLENAME, $array);
```

This is row

```
Array ( [pin_code] => 854101 [ccode_1] => 5806 [ccode_2] => [ccode_3] => [ccode_4] => [ccode_5] => [ccode_6] => [ccode_7] => [ccode_8] => [ccode_9] => [ccode_10] => [ccode_11] => [ccode_12] => [ccode_13] => [ccode_14] => [ccode_15] => [ccode_16] => [ccode_17] => [ccode_18] => [ccode_19] => [ccode_20] => [ccode_21] => [ccode_22] => [ccode_23] => [ccode_24] => [ccode_25] => [ccode_26] => [ccode_27] => [ccode_28] => [ccode_29] => [ccode_30] => )
```

i just want to remove ccode_1(this is not fixed depends upon $ccode value) value and update it back to db.

but its not showing desired result as above.

Comment: Sample  code   http://jsfiddle.net/rv2fk7qz/5/

Comment: You need to explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve may providing some sample data set will be helpfull

Comment: This is row Array ( [pin_code] => 854101 [ccode_1] => 5806 [ccode_2] => [ccode_3] => [ccode_4] => [ccode_5] => [ccode_6] => [ccode_7] => [ccode_8] => [ccode_9] => [ccode_10] => [ccode_11] => [ccode_12] => [ccode_13] => [ccode_14] => [ccode_15] => [ccode_16] => [ccode_17] => [ccode_18] => [ccode_19] => [ccode_20] => [ccode_21] => [ccode_22] => [ccode_23] => [ccode_24] => [ccode_25] => [ccode_26] => [ccode_27] => [ccode_28] => [ccode_29] => [ccode_30] => )

Comment: Here is my DB image http://postimg.org/image/puia0qatn/

Comment: Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29047711/853360

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to unset the desired index just get that index and apply update

```
if (($key = array_search($ccode, $array)) !== false) {
$this->db->where('pin_code', $pincode);
$this->db->update(TABLENAME, array($key => ''));
}
```

Comment: @Kiranarya print_r($key); inside if check see what is the output or check if it actually coming in if part ? and make sure you do have a values in $ccode/$array